# Extend IIS session default time

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-config

I have a website that will be used by inspectors, they have to travel to various places and do their job, the default time by iis to hold sessions alive is too short. Where do I set a longer session time? I need for example 1 hour.

I check on IIS the ASP setting for the website and changed the default 20 mins to 60 mins but it is ignoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to define the session timeout in the sessionState element of the web.config file of your application.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You should check the following link for more detailed information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx